# Phonegap build error - New apps must be built with XCode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, build

I'm having problem with releasing update for my application on App Store. I launched first version through phonegap build website (https://build.phonegap.com/) couple of weeks ago and now while trying to upload updated version I get this type of error:

This bundle is invalid - New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with public (GM) versions of Xcode 5.1.1 or higher and iOS 7 SDK. Do not submit apps built with beta software.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could not submit apps with beta version.if you are working with xcode6 beta than install Xcode6 GM Which is lunched today and upload your app . Hope  it will help you..

Comment: I am not building apps with Xcode. I'm using Phonegap build website for generating an app. I didn't have any issues prior to this one.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it's a problem between Apple and PhoneGap/Cordova.

Take a look at this link: 
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/critical-apple-not-accepting-phonegap-builds-as-of-today

---

Jamie Loberman wrote:

To stop all errors in iTunes connect I had to:

- Recreate my certificates, p12 and mobile provisioning profile, in the provisioning portal
- Remove the old certs from phonegap build and add the new ones
- Increase the version number of my app and then rebuild in phonegap build
- Submit using Application Loader

I also added 2 extra screenshots for the new screen sizes, but not sure if that's necessary.

Back to "Waiting for review" now, but at least I don't have the "beta entitlement" error any more.

---

Regards,
Renzi